# Conditional generator in `for` loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use condition in `for` loop in a succinct, clean way. Can I rewrite this

```
>>> for m in (m for m in range(10) if m < 5):
...     print m
```

to avoid doubled `for m in ...`, and still have a nice one-line `for`?

```
>>> for m in range(10) if m < 5: print m
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    for m in range(10) if m < 5: print m
                               ^
```

This is what I *don't* want:

```
>>> for m in range(10):
...     if m < 5: 
...         print m
```

I use python2.7

**Edit**

`range(10)`, it is just a toy example. A real use case would include, for instance

```
for m in items if any(cond(item) for cond in conditions)
```

or

```
for m in items if cond1(m) and cond2(m) or cond3(m)
```

Comment: Why don't you use: `for m in range(5):`?

Comment: Jeeez, it is just an example!

Comment: It would be better if you can give us real use case.

Comment: Surprising how little traction this question received: folks coming from other languages to python  spot the awkwardness and repetitiveness. This question is about how to reduce those downsides.Apparently there is no real way - but that does not invalidate the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume that you actually meant to do something more complex that would actually require the `if` statement, what you should consider doing is defining a generator to produce the relevant sequence.

e.g. instead of:

```
for m in candidates:
    if isvalid(m):
        ... do something ...
```

Write:

```
def valid_candidates(candidates):
    for m in candidates:
        is isvalid(m): yield m

for m in valid_candidates(candidates):
    ... do something ...
```

That way the complex condition is replaced by a descriptive name and the for loop is as simple as it can possibly be. Also, you can test the loop logic separately from the processing logic which you cannot if you mix the two together.

Comment: What I want is to have this generator in-line with `for`

Comment: and what I'm suggesting is that you write clear testable code instead.

Comment: The question is a good one, whether python is so weak to not be able to support is another

Answer (score 1):

> This is what I don't want:

```
>>> for m in range(10):
...     if m < 5: 
...         print m
```

That's fine, you could also do something like this:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> from operator import gt
>>> for m in filter(partial(gt, 5), range(10)):
        print m

    
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: I mean really?  Having a single line conditional should neither be rocket science or awkward.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects You are right I'm not sure why I wrote that at the time

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ifilter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) and lambda or any other function.

```
from itertools import ifilter

for m in ifilter(lambda x: x<5, range(10)):
    print m
```

Produces:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```